# Java compilator concludes that variable is Double, crashes as it is actually Long

Tags: java, android, nosql

I've been working on an android application using Firebase NoSql database and ran into something really weird. Application crashes with the error

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Double
    at com.sinic.mindfuck.DatabaseController$1.onDataChange(DatabaseController.java:52)
    at com.google.firebase.database.Query$1.onDataChange(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:183)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:75)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:63)
    at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:55)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6944)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

Code context:

```
final HashMap<String, Double> values = new HashMap<>();
mDatabase.child("rooms").child(roomId).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
  @Override
  public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                Object returnValue = dataSnapshot.getValue();
            if(returnValue != null) {
                for(Map.Entry<String, Double> value :  ((HashMap<String,Double>)(returnValue)).entrySet()){
                    values.put(value.getKey(), value.getValue());
                    if(!(value.getValue() instanceof Double)) {
                        Log.e("inside", value.getValue().toString()); // that's the line it crashes on
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Data in database:

```
85d54262:
  100m run: 0.3
  What: 100
  Jumping Jack: 0.1
  Push-up: 0.4
  Sit-up: 0.25
```

Basically there's a Map.Entry which has 'What' as it's key and has a Long value and if I try to do any opperation with it, it crashes, because compiler assumes that it's going to be a Double.

Never saw anything like it, any ideas?

Comment: It's not assuming that.  You're telling it that explicitly, when you do this: `((HashMap<String,Double>)(returnValue))`.

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should try to understand the stack trace. It says `Long` cannot be cast to `Double`. You should replace `Double` everywhere in your code with `Long`.

Comment: Question is why am I allowed to cast this way if one of the values is Long @JoeC?

And if I'm not allowed to cast it there, what is the alternative? I don't see a way to do it differently.

Comment: Thank you, @AbdulWadood. That doesn't answer my question though. As you can see from my dataset, most of the values there are floating point values, me changing from double to long is definetely not a solution

Comment: Can you post the code where you're creating the table in which you're inserting the values? Are you getting any lint warning on this line `for(Map.Entry<String, Double> value :  ((HashMap<String,Double>)(returnValue)).entrySet())` after running lint?

Comment: @AbdulWadood What table? Database one? I'm using nosql database that is currently readonly (Values were inserted by hand). lint message: `Unchecked cast: 'java.lang.Object' to 'java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String,java.lang.Double>.`


I'm more interested in this lint message that I get when I mouse-over the conditional statement inside the foreach loop:
`Condition 'value.getValue() instanceof Double' is redundant and can be replaced with a null check`
As far as I understand it, it should never be true (unless the value is null), but the value is not null and code goes inside the block.

Comment: Yes, I meant the one you're using in the database. Can you replace the loop with this code and try: `for(Map.Entry<String, Number> value :  ((HashMap<String,Number>)(returnValue)).entrySet()){
                    values.put(value.getKey(), (double)value.getValue());
                    if(!(value.getValue() != null)) {
                        Log.e("inside", ""+value.getValue().toString());
                    }
                }`

Comment: @AbdulWadood Still the same error. The JVM always assumes that it is Long, no matter what do you try to do with it before hand.

`java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Double`

Comment: On which line did you get the crash this time?

Comment: @AbdulWadood It crashed on the casting. I tried the answer where instead of casting (`(double) value.getValue()`) the doubleValue was used (`value.getValue().doubleValue()`) and that worked.

Comment: My bad can you just copy and paste this code once again, I missed an edit: `for(Map.Entry<String, Number> value : ((HashMap<String,Number>)(returnValue)).entrySet()){ values.put(value.getKey(), (double)value.getValue()); if((value.getValue() != null)) { Log.e("inside", ""+value.getValue().toString()); } }`

Comment: @AbdulWadood Tried it once again, it still crashed. Don't worry, there is an answer that fixed my problem already =). Thanks for trying.

Comment: The JVM isn't assuming its a Long-  its checking at runtime and it IS a Long.  Your assumption that it shouldn't be is the mistake.  As for why its a Long and not a Double-  no clue, you don't show sufficient code to tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use Number class

```
for(Map.Entry<String, Number> value :  ((Map<String, Number>)(returnValue)).entrySet()) {
    values.put(value.getKey(), value.getValue().doubleValue());
```

Comment: That actually worked, thanks. Do you have any explanation behind why the other things didn't?